# How the angular fringe width remains constant in Young's double slit experiment

Tags: waves

How the angular fringe width remains constant in Young's double slit experiment when the number of fringes goes on increasing [image]as we move above or below the central fringe,

in the text its given angular fringe width or angular fringe separation = (λ D/d)/D = λ/d,D is the distance of central fringe from the slit,d being the size of the slit,
also it states angular separation of fringes is increase in θ needed to increase the path difference by λ,
as we move above the central fringe I am finding the angle(angular fringe width) goes on decreasing,how its remaining constant.

Comment: Usually, to compute path differences in double slit experiment, we use small angles approximation $\tan (\theta )\approx \theta $

Comment: can u clarify what it means by " angular separation of fringes is increase in θ needed to increase the path difference by λ"

Comment: English is not my native language and maybe I don't understand your text properly. Usually, one say that to pass from a fringe to the next one, you have to increase the path difference $\delta =\frac{ax}{D}$ (first order on x) by $\lambda $ and so $x$ has to increase by $i=\frac{\lambda D}{a}$ (distance between fringe). The angular width of a fringe is $\frac{i}{D}=\frac{\lambda }{a}$, constant. But you have to suppose that the first order development in $x$ is OK. Maybe the validity of this development is the source of your questions ?